# What is a more efficient way to keep a daily ranking log for each user with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I have a database called RankHistory that is populated daily with each user's username and rank for the day (rank as in 1,2,3,...).  I keep logs going back 90 days for every user, but my user base has grown to the point that the MySQL database holding these logs is now in excess of 20 million rows.

This data is recorded solely for the use of generating a graph showing how a user's rank has changed for the past 90 days.  Is there a better way of doing this than having this massive database that will keep growing forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How great is the need for historic data in this case? My first thought would be to truncate data older than a certain threshold, or move it to an archive table that doesn't require as frequent or fast access as your current data.

You also mention keeping 90 days of data per user, but the data is only used to show a graph of changes to rank over the past 30 days. Is the extra 60 days' data used to look at changes over previous periods? If it isn't strictly necessary to keep that data (or at least not keep it in your primary data store, as per my first suggestion), you'd neatly cut the quantity of your data by two-thirds.

Do we have the full picture, though? If you have a daily record per user, and keep 90 days on hand, you must have on the order of a quarter-million users if you've generated over twenty million records. Is that so?

**Update:**

Based on the comments below, here are my thoughts: If you have hundreds of thousands of users, and must keep a piece of data for each of them, every day for 90 days, then you will eventually have millions of pieces of data - there's no simple way around that. What you can look into is *minimizing* that data. If all you need to present is a calculated rank per user per day, and assuming that rank is simply a numeric position for the given user among all users (an integer between 1 - 200000, for example), storing twenty million such records should not put unreasonable strain on your database resources.

So, what precisely is your concern? Sheer data size (i.e. hard-disk space consumed) should be relatively manageable under the scenario above. You should be able to handle performance via indexes, to a certain point, beyond which the data truncation and partitioning concepts mentioned can come into play (keep blocks of users in different tables or databases, for example, though that's not an ideal design...)

Another possibility is, though the specifics are somewhat beyond my realm of expertise, you seem to have an ideal candidate for an [OLAP cube](http://training.inet.com/OLAP/Cubes.htm), here: you have a fact (rank) that you want to view in the context of two dimensions (user and date). There are tools out there for managing this sort of scenario efficiently, even on very large datasets.

Comment: +1 If you could do some summarization of the results and keep them in the database instead of each individual row, that would probably help a great deal.

Comment: @Jon Was just thinking of adding that to my answer - good call!

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant I show a graph for the last 90 days not 30 days.

Comment: @James Simpson Okay. And do you indeed have ~200000+ users, or is something else about your model causing so many records to be created?

Comment: I do indeed have around 200,000 users, so the database is correctly storing 90 days for each user.

Comment: @James Simpson Fair enough - I've updated my answer based on these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run an automated task like a cron job that checks the database every day or week and deletes entries that are more than 90 days old?

Comment: That is what I currently do, but this makes the database still grow proportionately as new users join.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, do can you create some "roll-up" aggregate per user based on whatever the criteria is... counts, sales, whatever and it is all stored based on employee + date of activity.  Then you could have your pre-aggregated rollups in a much smaller table for however long in history you need.  Triggers, or nightly procedures can run a query for the day and append the results to the daily summary.  Then your queries and graphs can go against that without dealing with performance issues.  This would also help ease moving such records to a historical database archive.

-- uh... oops... that's what it sounded like you WERE doing and STILL had 20 million+ records... is that correct?  That would mean you're dealing with about 220,000+ users???
20,000,000 records / 90 days = about 222,222 users

EDIT -- from feedback.

Having 222k+ users, I would seriously consider that importance it is for "Ranking" when you have someone in the 222,222nd place.  I would pair the daily ranking down to say the top 1,000.  Again, I don't know the importance, but if someone doesn't make the top 1,000 does it really matter???

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I have somewhere in that range of users.  So, doing this was a temporary fix until the user base continued to grow and is out of hand once again.